# If $x_k→x$ and $T_k→T$ $\Rightarrow$ $T_k(x_k)→T(x)$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and for $x_k,x \in X$ assume $\|x_k-x\|_X→0$ and for $T_k,T\in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ are linear continious operators we assume $\|T_k-T\|_{\mathcal L(X,Y)}→0$.

I would like to show $$T_k(x_k)→T(x), k→ \infty.$$

Are there any known theorems that do state this result?

My attempt was to just plug in the limit since both do converge on their own but I think that does not do the job.

Answer (score 3):

$$\|T_k(x_k)-T(x)\|=\|T_k(x_k)-T_k(x) + T_k(x) - T (x) \|$$ $$= \|T_k(x_k - x) + (T_k-T)(x)\|\le \|T_k\|\|x_k-x\| + \|T_k-T\|\|x\|\rightarrow 0$$

Here we have used $\|T_k\|$ is bounded as $T_k$ is Cauchy.

Note that this is essentially the same as the proof that $x_ky_k\rightarrow xy$ whenever $x_k\rightarrow x$ and $y_k\rightarrow y$ for sequence of numbers, essentially because both of $(T, x)\mapsto Tx$ and number multiplication are bilinear.